# What is the most suitable statistical test for a series of data?

Tags: self-study

Sorry, this is a homework help question:

> In a bacterial growth experiment, ten μ (exponential growth rate constant) data points have been collected: one each of nine different concentrations of an antibiotic, plus one control (no antibiotic). What is the most appropriate statistical treatment for such a data set?

The background of the question is also that each data point has been collected by running a single experiment of measuring population against time, and calculating μ from the exponential phase of the growth curve (probably using linear regression of log(population) against time to get slope μ).

I'm thinking that running a chi squared test of each data point against the control would be sufficient to show significance, but I'm not really sure, and would greatly appreciate the input of the learned statisticians here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna get the best antibiotic concentration for bacterial cell death, then you need to fit a non linear model for dose-response relationship, for predict the [median lethal dose 50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LD50).

Check this tutorial to do this kind of analysis
http://www.graphpad.com/prism/tutorials/dose_response/dose_response_curves.htm

Also check this [paper](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4828275/dose-response.pdf) for concepts and to do this kind of analysis in R.